# sata controller without raid support

Tags: sata, controller, hotswap

I'm looking for a 4 ports pci or pci-express (not pci-x) sata controller with these features:
- real hot swap support
- no RAID support, or with RAID support that can be disabled through the controller bios interface or reflashing the bios

My need is to hot plug/unplug one or more different sata1 and/or sata2 disks from different brands size and speed (even at the same time), coming from my customers computers to perform lab activities on them, like backup.

I tried several Silicon Image controllers (3112,3114,3124) and Promise TX4. Everyone has issues: some disks are not seen or are dropped during the backup process while the Promise even hangs the host pc with some hard-drives. Adaptec raid (Serveraid 8s) controllers aren't transparent to the operating system and it seems there is noway to disable the raid.

What would you suggest?

Thank you!

Comment: what is the host OS?

Comment: @iPaulo it's a debian lenny 64bit

Comment: Did you find something? Did you try the Areca ARC-1300-4e?

Comment: yes! I bought a Silicon Image 3124 Addonics multilane PCI-Express ADSA3GPX8-ML. It works very well!

Comment: and no I never tried the Areca. Do you have any report about it?

Comment: No, it was a non sil image controller. I thought you might have found it and tried it since you had trouble with the sil image.

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider a SAS card? They usually allow also SATA.

Could something like Intel SASWT4I (WILDWOOD TRAIL) fit the bill? I have absolutely no experience with it, but on paper it does everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

Have had sucess with this card [LaCie 2Port](http://www.lacie.com/products/product.htm?pid=11068)  They also make a four port but it is not inexpensive.  Have had issues with some Startech cards not allowing Dell servers to boot and have not found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a SATA USB Dock?  http://www.thinkgeek.com/computing/a7ea/

Not sure what performance you are trying to achieve but this could be handy.

Comment: yes I did, but usb is too slow for a professional use and all those devices are too much fragiles: they are not supposed to be used several thousands times in a year. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned fragility in a comment: Be really careful, as SATA plugs aren't supposed to be used thousands of time, in fact they are really fragile, as I have learned the hard way just two days ago.

For this kind of use I would try to find a controller with e-sata ports since they are designed for much greater stress.